# Leapp upgrade : no matches found for the following disable plugin patterns : subscription-manager

Tags: centos, migration, upgrade

I’m trying to elevate from CentOS 7.9 to Alma8. I’m following [the official guide](https://almalinux.org/elevate/), but I’m stuck at `leapp upgrade`. I have the following error :

```
STDERR:
No matches found for the following disable plugin patterns: subscription-manager
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Warning: Package marked by Leapp to install not found in repositories metadata: python3-nss easymock ldns-utils ivy-local python3-javapackages
Warning: Package marked by Leapp to upgrade not found in repositories metadata: gpg-pubkey
Error: Error downloading packages:
  Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.almalinux.org/mirrorlist/8/baseos [Failed to connect to mirrors.almalinux.org port 443: Connection timed out]
```

(`subscription-manager` is for RHEL, and i'm trying to Elevate to AlmaLinux 8, why do I have to install this package ?)

I don't get any errors in the `/var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt` file, only `info` or `low` risk factors.

`leapp preupgrade` went successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided seems to be related to package management and repository configuration issues on a Linux system. It appears that there are conflicts between different packages and repositories. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and potentially resolve these issues:

Check for Duplicate Repositories:
The error message mentions that the "extras" and "extras-source" repositories are listed more than once in the configuration. You should check your repository configuration files and make sure that each repository is listed only once. These configuration files are typically located in the /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory.

Remove Duplicate Repositories:
Once you've identified the duplicate repository entries, you can remove the duplicates from the repository configuration files. Use a text editor to open the relevant files and remove the duplicate entries.

Update Repository Metadata:
After making changes to the repository configuration, you should update the repository metadata by running the following command:

**sudo dnf clean all
sudo dnf makecache**

Resolve Package Conflicts:
The error message also mentions a conflict between the npm and nodejs packages. You may need to resolve this conflict by uninstalling one of the conflicting packages or by finding a compatible version. You can try the following commands to remove one of the packages:

**sudo dnf remove npm**

## OR

**sudo dnf remove nodejs**

Be cautious when removing packages, as it may affect other software that depends on them.

Check for Leapp Errors:
The error message indicates a warning related to the Leapp tool and the "gpg-pubkey" package. Ensure that Leapp is properly configured and that the required packages are available in your repositories.

Check for Subscription Manager Issues:
The first part of the error message mentions "subscription-manager." If your system requires subscription management for software updates, ensure that it is properly configured and that any required subscriptions are active.

Check for Dependency Issues:
Sometimes, package conflicts can be caused by dependencies. You can use the dnf package manager to check for dependency issues:

**sudo dnf check**

Review Logs:
Check system logs and package manager logs for more detailed information about the issues. Logs are typically located in /var/log/ and can provide additional context for troubleshooting.

Consult Documentation or Support:
If you are unable to resolve the issues on your own, consult the documentation for your specific Linux distribution or seek support from your distribution's community or support channels.

Remember to proceed with caution when making changes to your system's configuration and packages, especially when removing packages, as it can impact the stability and functionality of your system.